# User registration in the Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a template for the user registration and the login using the Spring boot, Spring security, and the JSP. The project structure is provided below,

[image]

When I tried to register a new user, it returns to the URL of `registration` with the piece of code (from the POST method, provided below),

```
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }
```

The GET method to reach the registration page in the controller,

```
@GetMapping(value = "/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
        return "registration";
    }
```

The POST method in the controller to register the new user,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/registration")
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());
    return "redirect:/welcome";
}
```

I get a red flag like this in the POST form of the `registration.jsp` page provided below,

[image]

I guess the issue started with the `modelAttribute` and there is an error with the attribute.

What is the issue here and how to correct it?

Comment: Did your project compile ?

Comment: Yes, there is no error. The POST request is not successful and this is the issue.

Comment: What is the error did it shows during post request?

Comment: It returns to the `URL of http://localhost:8081/registration` from the POST request. I'm concerned about why the `modalAttribute` is red flagged. There must be where it started

Comment: Where is your form `action` attribute ?

Comment: Why do I need that here? The red flag dont come from the action btw